# How do I create a customized search-box for my application?

Tags: android, android-edittext, customization, search-box

How can I make a customized search-box for my android application? Something like this, for example :
[image]

Or if it's hard, is it possible to use the Android `SearchManager` in local app?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bughi stated, use custom background 9-patch drawables for your widget.
The second image consists of EditText and ImageButton placed next to each other.
Use 9-patch drawable like this for EditText [image: background drawable for EditText] and 9-patch drawable like this for ImageButton [image: background drawable for ImageButton].
Sure use selector as `android:background` for widget states as normal, pressed and focused.

First image can be achieved also by using attribute `android:drawableRight`.
Overriden `onTouchEvent()` method of your widget can look like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && event.getX() >= getWidth() - getCompoundPaddingRight()) {
        // search drawable was touched
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use your own images as background instead of the default ones.

For the `EditText` view i suggest looking into [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) for it to be able to resize smoothly on any screen.

Answer (score 1):

For the background I think it's easier to use a drawable shape like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <padding 
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:bottom="8dp" />

</shape>
```

The radius gives the background the rounded borders and can be easily adjusted, so is the size changing the padding.